# How to add a description to a .vssettings file

Tags: xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vssettings

I'm trying to add a description tag into the vssettings file so I can keep apart the various vssettings file I'm using.

Comment: You can name the file any way you want.  Pick a descriptive name.

Comment: Sure, but that leads to all kind of names like 'Current' 'Best' etc. You can add some xml that would even show up in Visual studio, if only I know the schema...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's for personal use or you're okay with non-localised strings, simply add `DisplayName` and `Description` elements with the text in them:

```
<UserSettings>
    <DisplayName>My Settings</DisplayName>
    <Description>The description to display.</Description>
    ...
```

If you want localised strings or to load them from the resource file belonging to a package, there are `ResourceID` and `ResourcePackage` elements that may be specified. (This snippet comes from `General.vssettings`, which is included with Visual Studio 2010, though I've also tested it with resources in my own VSPackage.)

```
<UserSettings>
    <Description>
        <ResourceID>#14839</ResourceID>
        <ResourcePackage>{DA9FB551-C724-11d0-AE1F-00A0C90FFFC3}</ResourcePackage>
    </Description>
    <DisplayName>
        <ResourceID>#14838</ResourceID>
        <ResourcePackage>{DA9FB551-C724-11d0-AE1F-00A0C90FFFC3}</ResourcePackage>
    </DisplayName>
    ...
```